# Facial Expression recognition accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm currently working on facial expression recognition using keras. I have gone through several tutorials and applied those guidelines. But I could not achieve an accuracy above 57%. I want to achieve atleast 90% prediction accuracy on my model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Dropout, AveragePooling2D
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

num_classes = 7 #angry, disgust, fear, happy, sad, surprise, neutral
batch_size = 256
epochs = 100
num_features = 32

with open("fer2013.csv") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

lines = np.array(content)

num_of_instances = lines.size
print("number of instances: ",num_of_instances)
print("instance length: ",len(lines[1].split(",")[1].split(" ")))

x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = [], [], [], []

for i in range(1,num_of_instances):
    try:
        emotion, img, usage = lines[i].split(",")
          
        val = img.split(" ")
            
        pixels = np.array(val, 'float32')
        
        emotion = keras.utils.to_categorical(emotion, num_classes)
    
        if 'Training' in usage:
            y_train.append(emotion)
            x_train.append(pixels)
        elif 'PublicTest' in usage:
            y_test.append(emotion)
            x_test.append(pixels)
    except:
        print("Error found")

#data transformation for train and test sets
x_train = np.array(x_train, 'float32')
y_train = np.array(y_train, 'float32')
x_test = np.array(x_test, 'float32')
y_test = np.array(y_test, 'float32')

x_train /= 255 #normalize inputs between [0, 1]
x_test /= 255

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 48, 48, 1)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 48, 48, 1)
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')

print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')



model = Sequential()

#1st convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(48,48,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5,5), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#2nd convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#3rd convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())

#fully connected neural networks
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("weights_new/emotionweights.h5",
                             monitor='val_loss',
                             verbose=1,
                             save_best_only=True,
                             mode='min')

earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                          min_delta= 0,
                          verbose= 1,
                          patience= 9,
                          restore_best_weights=True)

redule_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',
                              factor= 0.2,
                              patience= 3,
                              verbose= 1,
                              min_delta= 0.0001)

callbacks = [earlystop, checkpoint, redule_lr]

from keras.optimizers import Adam

gen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = gen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=64, epochs=epochs, callbacks=callbacks, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

fer_json = model.to_json()
with open("weights_new/json_model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(fer_json)
```

I used the above code to get almost 57% accuracy on test data.
Are there any other architectures or procedures which would help me get 90% accuracy??

Comment: Note: I'm using fer2013.csv dataset

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Okay. I have edited my question.